# *Why* doesn't SizedBox's width and height have any effect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In the following example, I'd like a red box (300x300) containing a blue button (100x100).
So I have:

```
-Center
 - Container (300x300, red)
   - SizedBox (100x100)
     -  FlatButton (blue
```

What I get is a 300x300 button. The button is expanded to the size of the Container. SizedBox is not constraining the button. **Why?**

I'm aware we can fix it with:

```
-Center
 - Container (300x300, red)
   - SizedBox (100x100)
     - Center
       -  FlatButton (blue
```

Why is this necessary? Why isn't SizedBox sufficient?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: content(),
    ));

Widget content() {
  return Center(
          child: Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  child: FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("Tapped button.");
                      },
                      child: Text("tap me")))));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem so. Which is FlatButton? If sized by its parent, then it should not end up being 100x100 (not 300x300). If sized by its child, it should be slightly larger than the text.

Comment: color: Colors.red, **alignment: Alignment.center**, child: SizedBox(